# maven created ear unable to startup correctly in wildfly 8.0 with error message ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

I have a maven created project that i am trying to run in eclipse kepler using wildfly 8.0 application server. The application fails to start correctly with this ambiguious error message

```
22:50:50,754 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.ApplicationEAR.ear.verification.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:809)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:223)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.ApplicationEAR.ear.verification.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:541)
... 6 more

22:50:50,760 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ApplicationEAR.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.ApplicationEAR.ear.verification.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.ApplicationEAR.ear.verification.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
 22:50:50,804 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "ApplicationEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "ApplicationEAR.ear")
 22:50:50,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
   JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.ApplicationEAR.ear.verification.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

22:50:51,072 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.2.Final
   22:50:51,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: verification.war) in 101ms
  22:50:51,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ApplicationEAR.ear (runtime-name: ApplicationEAR.ear) in 103ms
 22:50:51,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.0.0.CR1 "WildFly" started in 3940ms - Started 184 of 232 services (78 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
  22:50:51,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "ApplicationEAR.ear" (runtime-name: "ApplicationEAR.ear")
   22:50:51,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
  JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification, service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification, service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification, service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification, service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ApplicationEAR.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApplicationEAR.ear"."verification.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification] 
  JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./verification.UndertowDeploymentInfoService
```

Comment: The log message is exactly telling you what is wrong, so I suggest that you read the log message.

Comment: @zip your response is unless and unnecessary

Comment: Why is this so? You did not even bother to ask a question. I gave you at least a hint. So either write a real question or be thankful for every answer you might get. Thank you.

Comment: is that what you do all day on stackoverflow? write smart ass comments

Comment: Is Spring MVC actually inside this archive? If so, then where is it located? Could you post the contents of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not ambiguous, at the time of deployment a ClassNotFoundException is being thrown because the class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' can not be found by the deployer.

You will need to review the packaging and contents of your deployment to find why this class is not visible at the time of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your SpringFramework.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Do you have any reference about why this is the answer?

Comment: @stefan hi, i had a very similar problem and i noticed that after updating of spring, the problem was solved. i think the older version of spring tried to use some classes, which are not in the newer version of wildfly or hibernate nay more, so updating to the latest version, which is compatible to the latest version of server would be my first try:)